# IIS; print on shared printer with IUSR-user

Tags: c#, windows, iis, printing, iis-10

I’m trying to print to a shared printer from a IIS Windows 10 server with the IUSR user. So far unsuccessful.

The print job works with every other user, so it must be the authorization. Local printers are no problem.

On the IIS-server PHP starts a little C# application for server side printing an image. The printer is a shared printer on another Windows 10 pc in the (privat) network. There is no domain controller or something like that.

I have tried so far:

- Add network service permissions to the IUSR-user:
  https://serverfault.com/questions/469944/how-to-add-network-service-to-users-permission-group/469961
- Set up the shared printer to a local port:
  https://superuser.com/questions/899808/add-network-printer-as-a-local-printer
- Switch to other users with other permissions in the c#-print-applikation:
  [C# How to change user context in app running on system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943207/c-sharp-how-to-change-user-context-in-app-running-on-system)

None of it works. Does anyone have a good idea or workaround?

Comment: try to set application pool identity as a network service using iis application pool advance setting [image](https://imgur.com/uQwg9ta)

Comment: @luckystriker is your issue resolved or still unsuccessful?