# Connect to network folder with user name and password C#

Tags: c#, network-programming

I want to open a file from another device within the network, but the main obstacle to logging in is what is the appropriate code for authentication to work C#

Process.Start(@"\192.168.1.42\z\a.accdb" );

[image]

Comment: I think the probmlem might be, that there is missing a '\':  Process.Start(@"\\192.168.1.42\z\a.accdb" ); And dor starting a process in another user context check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20630541/7965241

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700871/connect-to-network-drive-with-user-name-and-password
Already solutions suggested in a lot of other stackoverflow posts. The second answer from the above link is the one I want to recommend.